# グルーピング正規表現

Tags: python, 正規表現

ある正規表現を用いたpatternとtextを入力として、出力を次の例のように得たいです。つまり、patterにマッチしたテキストをそのまま出力するのではなく、patternの位置にある括弧をつけて出力として得たいです。textとpatternを引数に持ちこのような出力を行う関数を作りたいです。
pattern: `'(A)_(B|D)([0-9]+).*([a-z])'` text: `'A_B101_c1'` --> output: `'(A)_(B)(101)_(c)1'`

pattern: `'([A-Z])12(b|d)(.*)c([1-9]+)'` text: `'A12ba_Bc123'` --> output: `'(A)12(b)(a_B)c(123)'`

Comment: 正規表現はあくまで「マッチ」させるところまでなので、元の文字列にない文字を追加・置き換えたい場合には「置換」を使うことになります。

Comment: re.subは知っていますが今回の場合どのようなコードでしょうか？

Comment: 自分が回答したのはあくまで「括弧を付けて」の部分までです。追記された「パターンを引数に持ち…」は切り離して考えられるはずなので、一旦自分で調べてもらうか別の質問として投稿してもらった方がよいです。(複数の質問をまとめて行うのはよくありません)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> これを一般化してどのようなpatternにも適用可能にすることはできますか？

※ 入れ子(nested)になっている正規表現には対応していません

```py
import re

def replace_matched_strings(m):
    if m is None: return
    b, e, s = *m.span(0), []
    span = [m.span(i) for i in range(1, len(m.groups())+1)
            if m.group(i) is not None]
    for i, j in span:
        s.append(text[b:i])
        if i < j: s.append(f'({text[i:j]})')
        b = j
    if b < e: s.append(text[b:e])
    return ''.join(s)
            
pattern = r'(A)_(B|D)([0-9]+).*([a-z])'
text = 'A_B101_c1'
print(re.sub(pattern, replace_matched_strings, text))

pattern = r'([A-Z])12(b|d)(.*)c([1-9]+)'
text ='A12ba_Bc123'
print(re.sub(pattern, replace_matched_strings, text))

# (A)_(B)(101)_(c)1
# (A)12(b)(a_B)c(123)
```

Comment: 入れ子 `(..(..)..)` だけでなく、 `(..)?` によるマッチしないグループがあってもまずいですね。

Answer (score 0):

正規表現で `( )` カッコでくくったパターンにマッチした文字列は、「後方参照」という仕組みで後から参照することができます。
文字列の置換時に参照するには `\1` の形式で使用します。`()` の数に応じて `\2`, `\3` のように増えていきます。

単純な例として、「マッチしたパターンを `()` でくくりたい」なら、置換後の文字列として `(\1)` を指定すればよいです。

**re.sub の書式:**

```
re.sub（正規表現, “置換する文字列”, 置換対象の文字列）
```

念のため補足すると、"置換する文字列" の部分では `()` などの記号は記号のまま扱われます (ここで指定するのは正規表現ではありません)。

質問の一例目に当てはめると以下のような指定になりそうです。

```
re.sub(r'(A)_(B|D)([0-9]+).*([a-z])', r'(\1)_(\2)(\3)_(\4)', text)
```

参考:
[【Python入門】正規表現による文字列置換をマスターしよう｜re.sub](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/23421)

Comment: これを一般化してどのようなpatternにも適用可能にすることはできますか？引数として、patternとtextを持つような関数にすることはできますか？